# Tab Delimiter not working Batch Command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which reads and set values from a text file.
But the text file contains tabs for different variables

Batch file command:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=<TAB>" %%x in (input.txt) do set %%x
```

Text File(input.txt):

```
a=one     b=two     c=three    d=four
```

But the variables are not being set properly.

Answer (score 3):

Two points here:

- The *default* `delims=` value include the space and Tab as delimiters, so you don't have to include a `delims=` option, unless you want to *ignore* the spaces as delimiters!
- Your `tokens=*` option define *one token letter* in your `for` command (`%%x` in this case) that contain *all tokens* in the line. If you want to get *four tokens* you need to specify `tokens=1-4`, start the tokens-letter with another one, and process each token accordingly:

.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "%%a" & set "%%b" & set "%%c" & set "%%d"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this works even, if your textfile has several lines (with different / unknown number of tokens):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (input.txt) do (
  set line=%%i
  for %%x in ("!line:   =","!") do set %%x
)
```

the trick is: by enclosing a string in quotes, delimiter chars are not treated as delimiters any more. So adding a quote at the beginning and end of the string AND replacing each `TAB` with "quote comma quote" changes the string to:

```
"a=one","b=two","c=three","d=four"
```

which can happily be processed with `for %%x ...`